# Console error saying [loadimages view]: unrecognized selector sent

Tags: iphone

```
imageview = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)]autorelease];
    imageview.image = [[UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithString:@"homebar.png"]]autorelease];
    [[self view] addSubview:imageview];
    imageview.frame = CGRectMake(imageview.frame.origin.x, (imageview.frame.origin.y), imageview.frame.size.width, imageview.frame.size.height);
```

I'm using this code to add an image to an uiview bur it results in a crash showing the error
`[loadimages view]: unrecognized selector sent`

There is also a warning showing that: `loadimages may not respond to -view`

I'm just a beginner could any one please help me .

Thanks.

Comment: This error indicates that `self` in your 3rd line above refers to `loadimages`. Can you post the context for the code?

Comment: <Rant>People are killing me with the `[NSString stringWithString:@"homebar.png"]` stuff. Reminds of when people .ToString() a string in C# IT MAKES NO SENSE. A string literal (@"string") is an NSString*.</Rant>

Comment: i want to add images to an uiview ie why is used this code

Answer (score 0):

That would be because loadImages does not have the method `view` in it. You also have not posted any relevant code.

Comment: what should i do to add images and buttons to uiview